# Make ScalaFx working on both JDK 8 and 11

Tags: java, scala, java-11, scalafx

To my dismay I have realized [my open source ScalaFX application](https://github.com/OndrejSpanel/ScalaFromJS) does not run with JDK 11. The application was developed with JDK 8. I have read about a JFX module and I can see there exist versions of ScalaFX dedicated to JDK 11 and newer ([ScalaFX 12](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx)). The way I understand it it does not achieve what I want - I would have to build different versions of my application for JDK 8 and JDK 11.

Is there a way to make a single ScalaFX application working on both JDK 8 and 11?

Comment: JavaFX (which ScalaFX depends on) is not included in JDK 11 and newer. You can get it as a separate product here: https://openjfx.io/

Comment: I understand that. The issues is JavaFX 12 documentations says it requires at least JDK 11, therefore an application linked against it does not seem to be able to run at JDK 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I've both simplified and expanded upon my original answer.

To address your main question, I believe it should be possible to write a single *ScalaFX* 8 application that targets both *JavaFX* 8 and *JavaFX* 9+, provided that you stick to the *API* defined by the former. As a result, I would recommend compiling your application using a *Java* 8 *JDK* with *ScalaFX*/*JavaFX* 8. If you use a *Java* 9+ *JDK*, or build against any version of *ScalaFX* higher than 8, then you'll be unable to run your application with a *Java*/*JavaFX* 8 run-time.

(If you want to support new features of *ScalaFX*/*JavaFX*, then you have no option but to target the specific version in which they appear, which may require you to produce multiple versions of your application if you still need to support older releases. Since you've stated that that's not your goal, I'm targeting *ScalaFX*/*JavaFX* 8 here.)

Note that *Java* versions 8 and 11 are *long-term support* (*LTS*) releases; *Java* versions 9, 10 and 12 are not, and are more bleeding-edge.

As you're already aware, there are fundamental differences between *Java* 8 and the subsequent *Java* versions, following the introduction of *Jigsaw modules* in *Java* 9. *Scala* support for modules is still very primitive, and it currently more-or-less pretends that they don't exist, which actually helps in this case.

The primary issue that needs to be overcome is configuring the *Java Virtual Machine* (*JVM*) when running your application.

Incidentally, note that I'm using the term *JavaFX* to include [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io), which is the open-source version of *JavaFX*.

When running your application with *JavaFX* 8, there will be a single *JAR* file named `jfxrt.jar`, and all you need to do is ensure that you have that file on your classpath. This is basically the same requirement that your application has always had, so you should be good here. Incidentally, *JavaFX* 8 should still work fine with *Java* 9+, as *Java* 9+ needs to maintain compatibility with older, non-modular libraries.

However, when running your application with *JavaFX* 9+, things get a little more interesting...

Firstly, as a rule of thumb, if you're using *JavaFX* version *X* (where *X* is some version higher than 8), you typically must also use a *JVM* whose version is equal to or higher than *X*. That is, you should be OK running *JavaFX* 9 with a *JVM* version 11, for example. However, you generally cannot expect to use, say, *JavaFX* 11 with *JVM* version 9.

While *JavaFX* 8 has a single *JAR* file that includes the whole library, versions 9+ are packaged into a number of separate modules, each with their own *JAR* file:

- `javafx-base`
- `javafx-controls`
- `javafx-fxml`
- `javafx-graphics`
- `javafx-media`
- `javafx-swing`
- `javafx-web`.

If you don't need, say, the elements defined in `javafx-swing`, then you can ignore the corresponding *JAR* file. However, to play it safe, you'll likely need to require all of them, which is what I'll do here.

You need to tell the *JVM* that these are modules, and to load them when the application runs.

For example, let's say you've installed *JavaFX* 11 into a directory named `C:\JavaFX11` on your machine, such that the library's *JAR* files are located at `C:\JavaFX11\lib`. Let's also say that I have an environment variable, `JAVAFX_HOME` that identifies this latter directory. You now need to pass the following arguments to the *JVM* when running your application:

```
 --module-path %JAVAFX_HOME%
 --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web
```

These options are only valid for *JVM*'s of version 9 or higher. (Clearly, this is also for *Windows*; you'll need to do something similar for other platforms.)

If you *do not* do this, then you'll likely see an error stating `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`. (If you're seeing something different, can you update your question to show the results of running your *ScalaFX* 8 application under *JDK* 11?)

Of course, the trick is to have the script that runs your application detect the version of *JavaFX* installed. It might help if you require your user to define a `JAVAFX_HOME` environment variable that specifies the location of their *JavaFX* library installation. If it contains a file named `jfxrt.jar`, then you're using version 8, otherwise, version 9+. In the latter case, you might also want to verify that you're using a version 9+ *JVM* before supplying the additional arguments.

There are still some potential banana skins (that can result in run-time errors) if you violate any of the module-restrictions defined in any libraries packaged as modules. Provided you stick to the published *JavaFX* 8 API specification, and do not try to access private implementation classes, you should be good.

**UPDATE 2**: Address further comments.

> I am not interested in any newer features, my only goal is to make old Java 8 application runnable with new JDKs, including JDK 11 and 12. If I would like to distribute JFX 8 (a single jar `jfxrt.jar` you have mentioned), how do I get it? I found maven artifacts only for JFX 11 and newer, downloads at [gluonhq.com/products/javafx](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx) also start with 11)

As you're aware, *JavaFX* 8 is bundled as part of the *Oracle Java* 8 *run-time environment* (*RTE*). This *Oracle* version of *JavaFX* is, in any case, proprietary and distribution of it with your product is probably unwise.

Also, as you're probably aware, the *OpenJDK* 8 *RTE* release does *not* bundle *JavaFX*, leaving users to install *OpenJFX* 8 themselves. In this latter case, there is no artifact available in any repository for this release, as it wasn't until modularization that it became possible to package *JavaFX*.

My understanding is that *Gluon* only recently took on supporting *JavaFX* (as *OpenJFX*), making standalone downloads available, and providing packaged artifacts available on the [*Maven Central Repository*](https://mvnrepository.com/), only as of *JavaFX* 11. Prior to them stepping up, it was the responsibility of the *Oracle* controlled [*OpenJFX* project](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/). The latter still hosts the [official *Mercurial*-based code base](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/jfx-dev/rt), but have updated most of their links, including download links, to the *Gluon* site.

It appears from *Googling* "*OpenJFX* 8 download" that there are not too many options available, but building [your own version from the sources](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX+8u) is one possibility. Using something like the [*wayback machine*](https://archive.org/web/web.php) is another. If you're running on *Linux*, a number of distributions still provide *OpenJFX* 8 releases in their repositories.

Maybe you could report the lack of a *JavaFX* 8 run-time to *Gluon* and see if they're prepared to release one?

However, there's a bigger problem brewing: the main issue you face is that *JavaFX* is not a *pure Java* library. It contains a number of platform-specific libraries that are referenced from the *JavaFX JAR* file(s). Just bundling your own version of `jfxrt.jar` will not work, as the underlying libraries for each platform will be missing.

Even if you can overcome that issue, you would need to ship a different version for each supported platform (*Windows* 64-bit, *Windows* 32-bit, MacOs, etc.) with the appropriate bundled version of *OpenJFX*.

You might want to consider dropping support for *JavaFX* 8, since you can then add platform-dependent library dependencies to your application build, and use an *SBT* plugin such as `sbt-native-packager` to bundle your *JavaFX* dependencies into platform-specific installation pacakages.

If you still need to support *JavaFX* 8, you currently have little option but to rely upon the user providing *JavaFX* themselves.

> I have tried a JDK 8 directory containing `jfxrt` (which is `Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext` for me) to the classpath of the application running under JDK 11 and the application was unable to start, with the exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method" with additonal information "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/SharedSecrets"

It's hard to say exactly what is causing this problem, without seeing your code, how it was run, and the full output from the application. Can you update your questions to include that information?

Comment: I am not interested in any newer features, my only goal is to make old Java 8 application runnable with new JDKs, including JDK 11 and 12. If I would like to distribute JFX 8 (a single jar `jfxrt.jar` you have mentioned), how do I get it? I found maven artifacts only for JFX 11 and newer, downloads at https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ also start with 11).

Comment: I have tried a JDK 8 directory containing `jfxrt` (which is `Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext` for me) to the classpath of the application running under JDK 11 and the application was unable to start, with the exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method" with additonal information "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/SharedSecrets".

Comment: @Suma I've updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: I think for my application the most portable way is to drop JFX completely. The application is very simple and porting it to Swing took my about an hour, definitely less work than what seems to be necessary to provide support for JFX for the wide JDK range.

Comment: @Suma: did you use a scala wrapper for swing or did you do it in java?

Comment: @costa Scala wrapper. I am quite happy with it. I already had experience with it, it was only for this project I chose ScalaFX as I wanted to use something more "modern".

Comment: @Suma: could you please post the link to the wrapper library? Thanks

Comment: [Scala Swing](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing) - use `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "2.1.1"`